# predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X' with loaded model

Tags: python

in my IoT project I would like to launch by a JavaScript file this simple Python script where a previously trained model is loaded and some vital signs data are analyzed. I already read similar topics but I was not able to figure out where my mistake is.

The command is:

```
 python3 script.py 98 22 97 37
```

The script:

```
import sys
import joblib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn


def main():
    data = [sys.argv[1:]]
    model = joblib.load("iot_model.joblib")
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[' HR (BPM)', ' RESP (BPM)', ' SpO2 (%)', 'TEMP (*C)'])
    x = df.astype(np.float32)
    prediction = model.predict(x)
    print(prediction)


main()
```

and this error is returned:

```
TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

The format of X is exactly the one used in the training phase.
Thank you in advance for your patience.

Comment: Can you provide iot_model.joblib?

Comment: when you do `data = [sys.argv[1:]]`, your `data` then is equal to `[['98', '22', '97', '37']]`. is that what your model prediction's expected input ?

Comment: @AcaNg yes, data is equal to that. But the expected input for a prediction is a dataframe of float-32 values.

Comment: then make sure `data`'s shape matches prediction's input shape (by modifying data's shape. currently, it's `(1,4)`)

Comment: What is the type of model you load with the `load` function? Since it loads pickled objects, it would help to know.